# Action Name not showing Up In URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to create a form in a view and am running into trouble with the routing; it seems to be totally ignoring the action name that I am providing. Here are my controller methods (Controller is called "MyController"):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateNewRequest()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            MyViewModelClass model = new MyViewModelClass();
            return View("CreateNewRequest", model);
        }
        else
        {
            return DisplayModelStateError(ModelState.Values);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateNewRequest(MyViewModelClass model)
    {
            //code to process the view model
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

In my view, I have tried several variations of the same thing to render a form, including:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateNewRequest","My",FormMethod.Post))
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateNewRequest","My"))
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateNewRequest","My",null,FormMethod.Post))
```

They all fail when the user clicks the submit button; I get an error that says:

> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /My

What is especially odd is that if i reverse them (which I know to be incorrect), I get an error message implying it looked for the action as opposed to totally ignoring it. For example, if I try

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("My","CreateNewRequest",FormMethod.Post))
```

I get the following error message:

> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /CreateNewRequest/My

Any ideas here?

Comment: Can you try 
@using (Html.BeginForm("My","CreateNewRequest",FormMethod.Post,null))

Comment: Tried that and the same thing with the first two arguments reversed, both fail, same as the other ways.

Comment: Does break point hits to CreateNewRequest? @RobertoGuzman